# delete 1 item from local storage array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a local storage item as per below

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
cityName
:
"durban"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
cityName
:
"cape town"
__proto__
:
Object
```

I would like to delete 1 item only, based on whether the cityName matches the local storage item i.e if the user clicks "durban" then delete durban.

I already am able to get the name from the click

```
  deleteCity(event){
    var target = event.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(target);
    var getLSCityName = localStorage.getItem('savedLocations');
    var getLSCityNameArr = JSON.parse(getLSCityName);

      for(var i = 0; i < getLSCityNameArr.length; i++){
        if (getLSCityNameArr[i].cityName == target){
          getLSCityNameArr.splice[i].cityName;
          localStorage.setItem('savedLocations', JSON.stringify(getLSCityNameArr));
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: after you "*do something here*", you'll need to, a) JSON.stringify it, then b) write it back to localStorage - if the `savedLocations` represents an array, then use array filter method to remove the desired item

Comment: what is the 'local storage'? Is it an array? object?

Comment: it is an array. I have updated my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
please try like this

function deleteItem(index){
            var getLSCityName = localStorage.getItem('savedLocations');
            getLSCityName.splice(index,1); // delete item at index
        }
```

Comment: ok this works `deleteCity(event){
    var target = event.currentTarget.id;
    var getLSCityName = localStorage.getItem('savedLocations');
    var getLSCityNameArr = JSON.parse(getLSCityName);

      for(var i = 0; i < getLSCityNameArr.length; i++){
        if (getLSCityNameArr[i].cityName == target){
          getLSCityNameArr.splice(i, 1);
          localStorage.setItem('savedLocations', JSON.stringify(getLSCityNameArr));
        }
      } 
  }`