# How to grab an item from local storage that's rendered in the particular div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delete a particular item from the local storage on clicking on a button inside one of the displayed divs.

When I press the button, the needed div is deleted, but I can't get it removed from local storage, so when the page's refreshed it appears again.
Local storage
Key: watchList
Value: ["tt0089880","tt0489270","tt0387564","tt0432348","tt1201607"]

```
fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movies[i]}&apikey=123`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((movie) => {
  containerList.innerHTML += `<div class="movie">})

//here I try to delete it from the local storage, but it doesn't work

containerList.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
  if (e.target.matches(".watchlist")) {
    tgt.closest(".movie").remove();
    localStorage.removeItem()
  }
})
```

I don't know how to connect the needed index of the Local Storage array to a particular DIV.

The full code is here: https://codepen.io/btb8293/pen/KKoLOmZ

Comment: Did you tried like `localStorage.removeItem("watchList")` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, doesn't help. I need somehow to connect the div I delete with Local Storage index.

Comment: Can you please give us the schema of your localStorage items that get rendered into said DIVs?

Comment: You can add a data attribute to your div like data-id to be able to identify that div in the localStorage. You can retrieve it with el.dataset.id

Comment: Here is the scheme: ["tt0089880", "tt0489270"] 0: "tt0089880" 1: "tt0489270"

Comment: I would try to to delete everything from localStorage just to be sure that the problem is in that part of code
localStorage.clear();
And after that search further
And I am sorry, where is the key of it? ["tt0089880", "tt0489270"] 0: "tt0089880" 1: "tt0489270" You have name the key zero (0)?

Comment: 1) If I understood correctly at the moment you can not delete the whole key, so you need to solve that first
2) To remove an element from array of your local.storage you need to grab your array  from local.storage (getItem) and after that X.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('watchList', JSON.stringify(X));

Comment: I can delete the whole key now on click (localStorage.clear()). But the 2d part doesn't work.

Comment: var test = localStorage.getItem('watchList'); 
console.log(test);
Do you have smth in console?

Comment: yep, I get ["tt0360717","tt0387564","tt0167260"]

Comment: The idea is that you take your array, splice it, and set it to localStorage
var oldList = localStorage.getItem('watchList');
oldList.splice(index,1);
put it to variable and then localStorage.setItem("watchList", YouNewArray);
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878705/delete-1-item-from-local-storage-array
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage

Comment: I just can't figure how to make that index. How to connect the relevant index of the array with the button that I click.